# ¿Cómo concatenar correctamente una función js dentro de un servlet Java?

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

Estoy usuando servlets para la creación de una aplicacion web. Estoy llamando a un código html con javascript pero cuando le envío datos a la función `onclick` falla porque no está concatenado correctamente ya que le hacen falta las comillas simples:

```
out.println("<li id='piloto'><a onclick='myFunction("+p.getNombre()+")'>"+p.getNombre()+"</a></li>");
```

donde dice `'myFunction("+p.getNombre()+")` debería ser `'myFunction('"+p.getNombre()+"')`, pero esto rompe la secuencia del código porque cuando crea el código en el html solo aparece *myfunction* y el contenido aparte, no dentro de la función.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con String.format, ejemplo

```
string name = p.getNombre();
string liElement = String.format("<li id='piloto'><a onclick='myFunction('%s')'>%s</a></li>", name, name);
```

Comment: pero este codigo va en el servlet

Comment: a perdón, en ese caso puedes usar string format, déjame corregir la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Yo recomendaría que no escribieras directamente el código HTML en el servlet. Mejor usa [JSP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm) o alguna tecnología similar.

Dejando a un lado la recomendación, podrías simplemente escapar correctamente el texto de la siguiente forma

```
out.println("<li id='piloto'><a onclick=\"myFunction('"+p.getNombre()+"')\">"+p.getNombre()+"</a></li>");
```

Espero haberte ayudado